# Reset loop on ESP32C3 USB interface

Tags: usb, esp32, reset

I have a circuit with a soldered ESP32C3 module:

[image: esp schematic]
[image: usb schematic]

This fairly closely mimics the schematic of a dev board with the same module. The ESP is at least partially functional, because when I attach to Linux I get a USB enumeration - but it continually cycles between connecting and disconnecting:

```
[2293762.357573] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[2293762.502075] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=303a, idProduct=1001, bcdDevice= 1.01
[2293762.502079] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2293762.502081] usb 1-4: Product: USB JTAG/serial debug unit
[2293762.502082] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Espressif
[2293762.502083] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 34:B4:72:00:B1:B8
[2293763.051012] cdc_acm 1-4:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[2293763.051038] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[2293763.051039] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
[2293764.553309] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 5
[2293764.847586] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[2293764.988644] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=303a, idProduct=1001, bcdDevice= 1.01
[2293764.988648] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2293764.988649] usb 1-4: Product: USB JTAG/serial debug unit
[2293764.988650] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Espressif
[2293764.988651] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 34:B4:72:00:B1:B8
[2293764.990565] cdc_acm 1-4:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[2293767.000409] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 6
[2293767.297642] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[2293767.438644] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=303a, idProduct=1001, bcdDevice= 1.01
[2293767.438647] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2293767.438648] usb 1-4: Product: USB JTAG/serial debug unit
[2293767.438649] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Espressif
[2293767.438650] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 34:B4:72:00:B1:B8
[2293767.440575] cdc_acm 1-4:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[2293769.448192] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 7
```

The same behaviour appears to happen in Windows (though I don't have logs).

Based on the likes of https://www.reddit.com/r/esp32/comments/ivtdzf/esp32_keeps_disconnecting_and_reconnecting_from/ , some people describe this as being caused by a weak PSU. Mine is an on-board SMPS, so I probed for brownouts but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was caused by lack of a proper strap config; from the [ESP32C3 Technical Reference Manual](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-c3_technical_reference_manual_en.pdf):

> ## 7 Chip Boot Control
>
> ### 7.1 Overview
>
> ESP32-C3 has three strapping pins:
>
> - GPIO2
> - GPIO8
> - GPIO9
>   These strapping pins are used to control the following functions during chip >power-on or hardware reset:
> - control chip boot mode
> - enable or disable ROM code printing to UART

Pulling GPIO9 (luckily I had this routed to somewhere harmless) low with 10k immediately solved the issue.